# Regular expression for graphviz node

Tags: regex, graphviz

I use the python standard library module **re** to search for nodes in the definition of a graphviz diagram:

```
import re

graphviz_node_regex = ??? # this regex is unknown
for m in re.finditer(graphviz_node_regex, string_containing_one_graphviz_diagram):
    # e.g. do something with the whole string of the match here
    match_string = m.group(0)
```

In the graphviz diagram i would like to find the nodes which may have the following syntax alternatives (node1, node2, node3, and their combinations of href/URL/target):

```
digraph foo {
  ...
  node1 -> node2;
  node2 -> node3;
  ...
  node1 [label="node1 name"];
  node2 [label="node2 name", href="../one_dir_with_underscores/file_with_underscores.html"];
  node3 [label="node3 name", href="../one_dir_with_underscores/file_with_underscores.html", target="_top"];
  node4 [label="node4 name", URL="../onedirwithoutunderscores/file_with_references.html#reference-with-separators", target="_top"];
  somenamewithoutseparators [label="name of node without separators"];
  some_name_with_separators [label="name of node with separators"];
  ...
  }
```

What is the one regex for all of the graphviz node alternatives?
What are the single regular expressions for each syntax alternative?

e.g. the regular expressions for the single syntax alternatives:

- node1: `\w*\s\[label="\w*\s\w*"\];`
- node2: `\w*\s\[label="\w*\s\w*", href="../\w*/\w*.html"];`
- node3: `\w*\s\[label="\w*\s\w*", href="../\w*/\w*.html",\starget="_top"];`

Comment: Add a small exact sample of the data, I think this can be done using a better alternative

Comment: `re.findall("node\d+\s+\[label=.*", lines)` will also find all the nodes in your example

Comment: I use sphinx-doc to generate .html files. The hyperlinked file is a .rst file which is the input to my python code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fkromer/eswp3/master/design_languages/build_automation_language.rst

Comment: You just want all the [label=... lines then?

Comment: The nodes do not begin with "node" but may have _spearation or not. I added two further syntax alternatives.

Comment: From the link what lines do you want? Does `print(re.findall(".*\[label=.*", lines))` not give you want you want?

Comment: I want to find and modify each node string individually. But i am not pretty sure if the processing gets easier if i find all node syntax alternatives or each node syntax alternative separately.

Comment: Does `for node in re.finditer("[^\s].*\[label=.*", lines)` give you what you expect?

Comment: Your second snipped is exactly the solution for the regex finding all node syntax variants. Thank you a lot!

Comment: No worries, you're welcome